# Git push fails in copied VM - stumped

Tags: ssh, git

I have been working on a codebase in a linux virtual machine on one system, and have been able to use git to clone/pull/push successfully on a remote repository.

I exported and copied this VM to another physical system and made some more changes to a branch, but I am unable to push it to the remote. I double-checked ssh-agent, made sure the correct key is loaded, but nothing works.

The error is

```
Connection closed by nnn.nnn.nn.nnn port 22
fatal: Could not read from the remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Have you tried ssh:ing to the git server with verbose output? Something like "ssh -vvv git@server". That might give a clue to why the connection is denied.

Comment: Good point. I've done that and it hangs on "expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY". I searched for this and found a Ubuntu bug report discussing this problem. Specifying a cipher allows the connection to proceed, so I'm now trying to figure out how to configure ssh / git to get this workaround in place.

Comment: I configured ssh to use the cipher which allows me to log in to the git host successfully, and now the git push error has changed to "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly". So close.